# OpenERP: How to display fields of two objects within the same view?

Tags: python, xml, one-to-many, odoo

How can I display fields of two record in the same tree view, Knowing that these tables are linked with OneToMany relashionship ?

here is my field:

```
    'class_id': fields.many2one('mod.class', 'Entree', required=True),
```

In my tree view :

```
    <field colspan="4" name="class_id" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list"/>
```

But this can just display foreign key but i need other fields

I'll appreciate any help .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenERP's addons folder goto addons > base > partner > partner.py, there you can see a field named 'address' which is a one2many field. Also you can find some related fields like 'mobile','phone','city' etc. which are related to the address field. These related fields can be used in the tree view.

This is the same thing that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, I use a [`related` field](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#relational-types) to display fields from a related table.

Answer (score 1):

Make related field or make a view(database) without table like many reports. Or make dashboard type view . It is upto you and your requirement.